# bootstrap multiselect box not displayed correctly

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

Im trynig to create a simple multiselect box but for some reason its not visible properly.

Here is my code:-

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="addRow" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add" />
<form id="form1">
    <div style="padding:20px">
        <select id="chkveg" multiple="multiple"></select>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/04Lgnkqs/

Answer (score 0):

After creating the select you should call the plugin on your select. something like this 
`$('#chkveg').multiselect();`
Refer [here](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started)